# MS Access: How to add pre-existing child to a collection on parent form

Tags: ms-access, parent-child

I have two tables: Parent and Child. The child records pre-exist in the table. I want to create a form for Parent with a subform with collection of Children, and want to a child. New children should never be created here. Selected children will have the FK-attribute set to the PK of the parent.

Is this possible in MS Access 2010?

Thanks...

Comment: Anything is possible. Are you saying that you want to assign children to various parents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to create the form and subform and set the `Allow Additions` property of the subform to `No`, this will prevent children being created. Next, add a button to the row called, let us say, `Assign`, the `Click` event of this button would then update the FK for children to the PK for parents, say:

```
Me.txtParentID = Me.Parent.txtID
```

Human nature being what it is, you will probably need a form or button that allows parents to be removed when they are mistakenly assigned.

You may wish to exclude assigned children from your form.

There are, of course, several other ways to do this.

**Edit**

Presumably you have some field in the child table that indicates a parent, so you can use that to filter the unassigned children. The record source of you pop-up form would be something like:

```
SELECT ID, Something FROM Children WHERE ParentID Is Null
```

You can still have the assign buttom which could use an OpenArg from the main form with a message box to confirm, the ID directly from the main form, or an additional small form to select a parent.

I do not recommend a pop-up. Unless you make it application modal, it is possible that the user will move the main form record without paying sufficient attention and if you do make it application modal it will be a nuisance.

A subform of assigned children would be safer or an assign form listing only unassigned children that includes a combobox based on the child table parent id foreign key to select a parent. This could be a continuous form.

Comment: I wish to exclude _unassigned_ children from the form, as there are many of them. I'd like to have something like an Add button, which will show a popup with all possible children, I would filter them, check some of them to be assigned and click OK. Is this possible?